# pytest: validating __init__ args with mock

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest.mock

I would like to write a test confirming `__init__` values

```
def test_foo(mocker):
    mock = Mock()
    mocker.patch(
        "Foo.__init__", return_value=mock
    )

    foo = Foo('bar')
    mock.assert_called_with('bar')
```

But i get the following error `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'Mock'`

I ignore the error via try/except around `foo = Foo('bar')` but now, pytest says mock was not called

```
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: mock('bar')
E           Actual: not call
```

Any idea how to validate `__init__()` args?

Thanks

P.S.
I also would not like `__init__()` to actually run hence mock and not spy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to patch the method while not returning anything (even by default a `MagicMock` would be returned):

```py
def test_foo(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch("Foo.__init__", return_value=None)
    foo = Foo("bar")
    mock.assert_called_with("bar")
```

Comment: this worked. thank you